# How do I make relative path using Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am writing Groovy script to load file located in my local system, i.e `C:/Data/Data.xls`

I wanted to make relative path using Groovy, so that this `Data.xls` file can be read from any location.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in Groovy is no different than doing it in Java.  Use the [`@Grab`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html) annotation to get [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) and use it to read your data.